# How to color a particular cell in a table which is stored in a variable as a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to develop a memory test mini game. Where upon clicking yes a table with some 4 rows having true/false will be displayed for few seconds. After that we will put two buttons "true" or "false" and the user has to click on these buttons in the same sequence as shown at the beginning screen. I want to highlight the cell with red color which is incorrect. But as it a string iam getting all rows in red color when i tried to color that particular incorrect one.
https://codepen.io/punjala-rakesh/pen/pxRvWp

```
var x = "";

var basenumber = 0;

$(".trueorflase").click(function(){

if($("#playingtable td").length != $("#actualtable 

td").length){

if(this.innerHTML != $("#actualtable 

td").eq(basenumber).html()){

x = x + "<tr>" + "<td>" + this.innerHTML + "</td" + 

"</tr" + "<br>";
document.getElementById("playingtable").innerHTML=x;
playingtablelength = $("#playingtable td").length;
document.getElementById("pol").innerHTML=playingtablelength;
}
else if(this.innerHTML == $("#actualtable td").eq(basenumber).html()){
x = x + "<tr>" + "<td>" + this.innerHTML + "</td" + "</tr" + "<br>";
document.getElementById("playingtable").innerHTML=x;
}
basenumber ++;
}
else if($("#playingtable td").length == $("#actualtable td").length){ `enter code here`
$("#GameisOver").show();   
document.getElementById("GameisOver").innerHTML= "Game is Over";
}
```

In the above code all the cells/rows are stored in string "x". I want to color a particular cell/row.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aRpOdb

Please find codepen.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro....it's working now